# Volume of a Hyperboloid using triple integration/shadow method

Tags: integration, volume

Could someone help me find the volume of the hyperboloid $$\frac{x^2}{1817}+\frac{y^2}{1817}-\frac{z^2}{10914}=1$$ with the limits in the $z-axis$ of $-130$ to $43$? I tried using triple integration, but I'm not sure how to convert the variable the in limit of the innermost integral into a number. I would also be open to any other methods of finding the volume.

Comment: The limits on $z$ given in the problem statement are a good starting point.  Using that as your outer variable of integration, can you set up nested integrals over $x,y$?

Comment: By "volume of the hyperboloid" do you mean 1. The volume of the solid of rotation about the $z$-axis enclosed by the hyperboloid and the two planes, 2. The surface area of the hyperboloid whose equation you've given, or 3. Something else? If "1.", the disk method for solids of rotation is easier than setting up a triple integral.

Answer (score 0):

Usually triple integration is used to find weight of a volume with the density function d(x,y,z). However you can still adjust your density d(x,y,z) = 1 in order to obtain the volume.

I suggest you to draw the volume by a mathematical tool to see the natural bounds before integration.

I think the double integral you are using is on XY-plane. Thus in order to define limits of integration you should put z=0. Then you get a circle equation

$\frac{x^2}{1817} + \frac{y^2}{1817} = 1$

Then if your differential is dxdy then the x values should be inside

$[-\sqrt(1817 - y^2) , \sqrt(1817 - y^2)]$

The outer integration bound (which bounds y values) is

$[-\sqrt(1817) , \sqrt(1817)]$

Finally you will have;

$\int_{-\sqrt(1817)}^{\sqrt(1817)}\int_{-\sqrt(1817 - y^2)}^{\sqrt(1817 - y^2)}F(x,y).dxdy$

Note that as you have limits on z-axis, you will arrange the integrand function $z = F(x,y)$ by these limits when the z-value crosses them.

Comment: I don't know how natural they are, but the problem states the limits of integration for $z$ as $-130$ to $43$.

Comment: @hardmath yes so you can write your F(x,y) function bounded below by -130 and above by 43. In fact the maximum z values here is about +/-104.4. So you only need to bound your F(x,y) function above by 43.

Comment: My point is that evaluating the expression $x^2 + y^2$ at $z=0$, as you have done, should probably be done instead as $z$ varies from $-130$ to $43$, making $z$ the outer variable of integration for simplicity.

Comment: @hardmath well if you really want to use triple integral then no calculations is done at z=0 for x&y. You then just put -104.4 to 43 as the outer integration limit which represent dz. But this way you will re-define the dx and dy integration limits. No need for functions which have circular XY-plane sections.