# Parametrizaction of a Hyperboloid

Tags: parametric, hyperbolic-geometry, parametrization, quadrics

I do not understand why when you revolve a hyperbola around a circle the respective parameters (cosh (v) and cos (u)) are multiplied by each other to get the parametric form of the hyperboloid. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could show me how these parameters are reached.

Comment: Have you, by chance, encountered either polar or cylindrical coordinates?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing a bit at the description you're looking at, but I think you're looking at 
$$
(\cosh (v) \cdot \cos (u), \cosh (v) \cdot \sin (u), \sinh(v))
$$

Think of your hyperbola in the $x,z$ plane, and think about what happens when you rotate a single point on the hyperbola around the $z$-axis, say $$(\cosh(v),0,\sinh(v))$$
Well, it's a circle of radius $\cosh(v)$ maintaining a height of $\sinh(v)$.  So the $z$ coordinate stays fixed, and the $x,y$ coordinates pass through $(\cos(u)\cdot\cosh(v),\sin(u)\cdot\sinh(v))$.  I'm not great at describing these things without chalk, but does that make sense?

Comment: (Just FYI): I assume OP's question is in relation to this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1656603/volume-of-a-hyperboloid-using-triple-integration-shadow-method